# Axios post request with array of objects

Tags: json, reactjs, web-services, .net-core, axios

i would like to post my array of objects data to .net core webservice.

this is my post method from react component.

```
async save(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var addition= this.state.addition;

    addition.basket = this.state.basket;

    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:62524/api/SaveBasket/", querystring.stringify({ addition: addition}))
        .then((error) => {
        }).catch((error) => {
        });
}
```

Data is not seeing after post.

this is my web service method,

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SaveBasket(object addition)
    {

        var user = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
        if (user != null && User.HasClaim(x => x.Type == "FIRMID:"))
        {
            //unitOfWork.Additions.SaveBasket(addition);
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }
```

The data is sent to the above web service block.

getting something like this --->> [object]

How can i post the array of objects ?

Comment: Did you bind the `save` function to your class? if not you can update it to be something like `save = async (e) => {`

Comment: yea i did but i think sent data to web service because SaveBasket is firing. but object addition from web service seems look like this --->> "[object]"

Comment: Can you debug where the data comes back to see what you are getting?

Comment: getting this >> https://prnt.sc/ok1rs5  ---- adisyon -> addition i translated for you

Comment: Actually, what I want to do is update the entity. @JohnRuddell